# PHP sessions - cannot retrieve session in firefox or chrome

Tags: php, session, browser

My HTML form is sent to a PHP page to process. I need to add a captcha to the form but am unable to change the HTML page to PHP and so have set a session for the displayed captcha in a capcha.php page which outputs as an image within the HTML form. When the page loads the session var is set but I cannot retrieve this session in the process PHP page.  It just  firefox or chrome where I am havin this issue.  It works in IE.

Code that sets session in the capcha.php:

```
session_start(); // start a session
$image = imagecreate(50, 20); //create blank image (width, height)
$bgcolor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0); //add background color with RGB.
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255); //add text/code color with RGB.
$code = rand(1000, 9999); //create a random number between 1000 and 9999
$_SESSION['code'] = $code; //add the random number to session 'code'
imagestring($image, 10, 8, 3, $_SESSION['code'], $textcolor); //create image with all the settings above.
header ("Content-type: image/png"); // define image type
imagepng($image); //display image as PNG
```

PHP process page:

```
session_start();

print_r($_SESSION['code']);
```

Can anyone assist?

***EDIT****
I think its something to do with the session being set in capcha.php which is added as an image to my HTML form.  If I go to capcha.php in the browser an then to process_email.php the session is set.  So therefore its not setting when being included as an image.  Does anyone know of a way round this issue?*

Comment: Why are you starting the session again in your **process.php** page ?

Comment: you say you can't retrieve session in firefox or chrome, so are you saying you can in IE? or is it you can't retrieve the session at all?

Comment: I can retrieve the session in IE, I have a value for session['code'].  I dont have any value in firefox or chrome.

Comment: @dreamweiver: Because that’s how sessions over multiple pages work …

Comment: use `session_start()` as first statement

Comment: @dreamweiver I have used session_start() on both pages as this is what is required when starting a session or accessing sessions on different pages.

Comment: @Amir I have put session_start() as the first statement on both PHP pages.

Comment: just to be sure. You **NOT** doing `session_start();
echo'<img src="captcha.php"/>';
print_r($_SESSION['code']); `, right?

Comment: The <img src="captcha.php"/> is in a HTML form with no PHP.  All the php code is in the captcha.php and the process.php page.

Comment: Are you sure that cookies are enabled in firefox and chrome?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an interesting question. Let me try to explain this in more details.

- When you start a PHP session normally you send cookie to user. When user opens some other page on your site you find `PHPSESSID` cookie in HTTP request header and take the session ID from the cookie. Then you find session for this ID on your server and load session data.
- Normally you set the cookie in main HTML document. But you don't because this is some static document you can not change.
- You set cookie in the image included in the HTML. I never did this before and I should admit I had no idea how the browser should behave in this case. Perfectly the cookie should be taken from the image and then used on all pages.

I did a test for this. And below are my results. I did everything in Chrome. In short, I can get the cookie in the form handling PHP file.

Open the HTML page. We can see there are no cookies on this page.
[image: No cookies for the HTML page opened for the first time]

On this page we load image and the image HTTP response has cookie specified.

[image: Image file with cookie for PHP session specified]

When I submit the form I get cookies defined in HTTP request. Have a look:
[image: Form submitted and cookie defined]

This works for me in Google Chrome as expected.

I suggest to check the domains. What is the full URL for the HTML page with form, image and the submit URL? Do they have exactly the same domain?

I did one more test and loaded image from different domain then HTTP page. But this does not work not only in Chrome but in IE 9 too. This is why I can not guess what you are doing.

I suggest to use development tools in Chrome and check all the cookies and page load requests.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth response, its much appreciated.  When I go through the process you explain, I seem to get the same results as yourself, however, it still does not print out the session in the process.php page even though I can session IDs have been set.

Comment: Im 100% certain the files are all on the same domain and have the same URL.

Comment: Hhhmm the session IDs appear to be different.

Comment: Do you know how to clean your cookies? You can open the page in incognito mode. Then I guess you might see that the cookie for the page is not set. Can you check this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to unset that session first before assigning to a value to it.

Comment: Tried that, its still empty

Answer (score 0):

don' forget to add a session_destroy() at the logout file and a condition like

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['session_value'])) {
}
```

is a better programming way.